# Install wampserver locally but store files on LAN?

Tags: wampserver

I searched and found a lot of questions relating to sharing my site on the LAN or accessing a WAMP on the lan.  I want to be clear:

I use WAMPserver 2.5 for local development so I want it on my Windows PC and I'm not sharing it with anyone.  But... I want the actual files to be stored on my \SERVER share for purposes of backup.  I can't seem to figure out how to tell WAMPserver to do that.  By default, it installs in C:\wamp and puts a www folder in that directory and looks for everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the WAMP icon in the task bar, then open the httpd.conf file under the Apache directory. Find the DocumentRoot setting, which is currently c:\wamp\www, and change it to your desired directory. Then, a few lines further down, do the same with your Directory setting. Save the file, and restart the WAMP server.

Comment: Or better still create a Virtual Host for your project and then you can create another for yrou next project. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for how to setup Virtual Hosts